# \ddot{a} character for strings

Tags: accents, characters

I'm looking for the `\ddot{a}` character which doesn't require me to put it into a formula or between `$` characters.
Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You mean the dieresis/umlaut? `\"{a}`.

Comment: Please provide some additional information, e.g., regarding the document class you use, the font(s) you use, and whether you use pdf(la)tex, xe(la)tex, or lua(la)tex. Separately, are you looking, in essence, to typeset "a with an Umlaut"? If so, you should probably be typesetting it either as `\"a` or input it directly (assuming that your text editor knows how to handle more than just the most basic ASCII set of characters).

Comment: I'm using a custom document class and I use pdflatex to compile the document.
Thanks, I tried with your suggestions and it works, but it gives me the same result of ddot: the a letter is in italic and it use another font.

Comment: @auino Please, add an example of what you're trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To typeset a letter with an Umlaut in text mode, you should *never* use the math-mode macro `\ddot`:

- the dots will not be placed properly according to *text-mode* conventions
- the argument of the `\ddot` command (if writing in German, likely `a`, `o`, or `u`) will be typeset in *math-italics* rather than the (probably desired) upright or "roman" text mode. (Incidentally, even if you *do* want the text in question to be set in italics, you should know that there are some subtle but noticeable differences when these vowels are set in text-italics or math-italics -- at least when using Computer Modern fonts. E.g., in math-italics the three vowels are slightly wider *and* the "lower-right tails" of the `a` and `u` are spaced a bit more widely.)

To typeset letters with an Umlaut (dieresis), you could

- Use the "standard TeX/LaTeX" method, viz., `\"a`, `\"o`, etc.
- If using `babel`, use the applicable shorthand command (e.g., with `german`, type `"a`, ...
- If using a minimally competent editor, you can probably enter the characters directly. (Be sure to also provide a statement such as `\usepackage[utf8]{fontenc}`.)

Any of these methods will automatically switch between roman and italics letters depending on which font shape is in effect when the commands are processed by LaTeX.

In addition, consider using a font family (such as Latin Modern) that contains optimized glyphs for characters with umlauts, adding also `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`